# Query to Delete consecutive repeated values in large database in my SQL using phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a table records with speed column in my database. Now the first 6 entries are same(consecutive repeated value) in different timestamp. I want to remove these repeated values a just take only single value.
after some time the speed varies and become 200 and then again remain constant then my query should also delete that consecutive duplicate values from my table records.

In simple words I want to filter my records table and make that table free from consecutive repeated values show only the single values in different timestamp.

speed in records table of database:
[image: speed in records table of database]

I've tried different queries to perform that some are these

```
DELETE t1 FROM records t1
inner join records t2
WHERE t1.speed = t2.speed AND t1.run_date_time < t2.run_date_time

DELETE FROM history 
WHERE id IN (
SELECT x.id
FROM (             
  SELECT id
  FROM history AS h1
  WHERE 
      speed = (SELECT speed
              FROM history AS h2
              WHERE                     
                    h2.run_date_time < h1.run_date_time
              ORDER BY run_date_time DESC 
              LIMIT 1)) AS x)
```

Comment: Select **one** DBMS (MySQL <> SQL Server) and remove excess tag.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: update your question  add  a proper data sample and the expected result

Answer (score 0):

Based on your second query I believe this is `history` (not `records`) table and it's MySql (LIMIT).

```
DELETE
FROM history 
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT x.id
  FROM (             
    SELECT id, lag(speed, 1, speed+1) over(order by run_date_time) != speed newFlag
    FROM history ) x
  WHERE NOT newFlag)
```